# Incompatible Types: Returning a new String object

Tags: java, string, oop

I've been working on a little project writing my own custom String methods. (replace,concat, etc...) to manipulate strings in an object oriented design.
In my class definition (MyString) I wrote a concat() method that has a return type of a MyString.

```
public MyString concat(MyString sent)
{
    char[] newString = new char[sequence.length + sent.sequence.length];
    for(int i = 0; i< sequence.length;i++)
    {
        newString[i] = sequence[i];
    }
    for(int i = sequence.length; i < newString.length; i++)
    {
        newString[i] = sent.charAt(i - sequence.length);
    }
    sent.sequence = newString;
    return sent;
```

In my driver A user will enter a string. and then be prompted to enter another string to be concatenated. when I go to call the method I'm getting an incompatible types error saying the String I'm sending into it (compString) can't be converted to a new MyString. I created a new MyString object, and sent in the new String, which I thought was the right thing to do...

```
MyString ms = new MyString(compString);
System.out.println("Calling the concat() method: " + ms.concat(compString) );
```

I want to concatenate compString onto the original string, both of with are MyStrings. How would I go about calling this method? "ms" being the reference variable to the original string. Do I need a new MyString object in order to accomplish this?

```
public MyString(String sent)
{
    origional = new String(sent);
    sequence = origional.toCharArray();   
}
```

Here is my constructor just in case.

Comment: What's `compString`?

Comment: @shmosel My guess is that it's just a `String`

Comment: Its just what I named the String

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem. Are you getting an error message, unexpected output, or both? Either way, please specify exactly what you're getting and how, using a [mcve].

Comment: *Unrelated:* What is `origional`, and what is the purpose of `origional = new String(sent);`

Comment: @shmosel Im getting an "Incompatible Types: cannot convert compString to MyString" error.

Comment: What type is compString? - is it a regular string??

Comment: You're sending `compString` which is a String not a `MyString` to your `concat` method... did you mean to send a String to `concat` or a `MyString`?

Comment: Keep in mind `MyString` and `String` will _never_ have substitutability. They are inherently different objects.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I need to send in a MyString

Comment: @RyanCorkwell You're not doing a very good job at explaining yourself. If you expect people to spend the time to help you, spend a little more time to make the question clearer.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways it is a regular string.

Comment: @shmosel i edited the question to be more clear, sorry

Comment: Now it's even more confusing. How can you say they're both `MyString` when you've already said `compString` is a String? And if `ms` is the original string, then you're just concating it to itself.

Comment: @shmosel Ok, compString is a String. compString being the String i want to add onto the original MyString or ms. Since my method takes in a MyString. What do i need to do in order to accomplish this?

Comment: `ms.concat(ms)`

Comment: @shmosel i tried to make a new    MyString..                                    
MyString ms1 = new MyString(compString)  called the method ms.concat(ms1);   and its returning an address

Comment: Why are you trying to make a new instance? What does the address have to do with your incompatible types? You originally said the address was expected. Do you know how `toString()` works?

Comment: @shmosel Ok, i see the confusion. I thought i mentioned i created my original MyString with MyString ms = new MyString(userString) so ms is the first string. I created a new Instance MyString ms1 = new MyString(compString)  to turn compString into a MyString. and then call the concat method ms.concat(ms1); when i try to print it just prints the address of ms1. When i want to print the joined MyStrings.

Comment: Much clearer. So just override `toString()` to return the original string.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a `String` into your `concat()` method, which expect `MyString`. Try wrapping it in your class first:

```
ms.concat(new MyString(compString))
```

I have to admit, this still doesn't make much sense. `ms` is already a wrapper for `compString`. Are you trying to concat a string to itself? Then just do `ms.concat(ms)`.

Comment: *"Then just do ms.concat(ms)"* Which OP already tried, and it worked *("I tried sending in ms")*. The question was about why `concat(compString)` didn't work, and you've answer that (so, +1 from me), but that last part of answer wis already covered by question.

Comment: @Andreas You may be right. Personally, I'm having a lot of trouble parsing the question, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString` function so that the `println()` function will properly print out your custom string.

You also need to match the expected `MyString` type parameter for your `concat(MyString sent)` function.

Something like:

```
class MyString {
    public String toString()
    {
        return sequence;
    }
}

MyString ms = new MyString(compString);
// making assumption that compString is a standard string
System.out.println("Calling the concat() method: " + ms.concat(new MyString(compString)) );
```

Comment: Lack of `toString()` will not cause Incompatible Types compilation error.

Comment: @Andreas OP did say "I tried sending in ms but it printed the address to the object just as I expected." Whatever that means.

Comment: @shmosel Sure, but that has nothing to do with the actual question, which is entirely about the Incompatible Types error. Nowhere is there a question asking how to not print "address" of object. OP accepted (expected) the printing of "address" as a non-issue, to showcase that code compiles when if was written differently. In no way is writing a `toString()` method an answer to this question.

Comment: I maintain that the original _intent_ of the OP was to print the concat'd string to stdout (at least the intent of the code snippet). I was addressing that with the suggestion to override ToString. I also addressed the type error in the code snippet.